# How do I get a value from a foreign key to populate a list with an associated value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following list in my ViewModel:

`public List<Objective> Objectives { get; set; }`

I also have the following repository method:

```
public async Task<List<Objective>> GetAll()
{
    return await _context.Objective.ToListAsync();
}
```

Finally I have the following method in a service which returns a ViewModel:

```
public async Task<ObjectivesViewModel> GetViewModel()
{
    var viewModel = new ObjectivesViewModel()
    {
        Objectives = await _objectivesRepository.GetAll()
    };

    return viewModel;
}
```

All of this works as expected.

My Objective Model looks like this:

```
public string ReferenceCode { get; set; }
public int TeamId { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; )
```

With the TeamId Model looking like this:

```
public int TeamId { get; set; }
public string TeamName { get; set; }
```

As it stands, the repository returns all, as it should, however what I'd like to do is to add the TeamName associated with the TeamId. How would I accomplish or approach this?

Comment: what do you mean by "replace"... do you mean, you don't want the TeamId to be returned with the view model? If that is the case, create ObjectiveViewModel that don't have TeamId... do the mapping from Objective to ObjectiveViewModel your self... or use AutoMapper

Comment: I've added some clarification and edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: you are asking something which you can google. even the most basic tutorials show you this. Lookup EF and ForeignKey and how to use navigation property or how to use alternative to lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

Make TeamId foreign key, and access team navigation property
Objective model:

```
public string ReferenceCode { get; set; }
public int TeamId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("TeamId ")]
public Team Team { set; get; }
public string Description { get; set; )
```

now you can access teamId or teamName

```
Objective obj = _context.Objective.FirstOrDefault();
obj.Team.TeamName
```

Comment: How would I get all elements, rather than just the first?